# Inoic : Ionic avatar is not displaying

Tags: ionic-framework

item-avatar not working in my project it's not showing item-avatar element at all.

```
  <ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
      <ion-list-header>
          Recent Conversations
      </ion-list-header>
      <ion-item>
          <item-avatar start>
              <img src="https://ionicframework.com/docs/demos/api/avatar/avatar.svg">
          </item-avatar>
          <ion-label>
              <h2>Finn</h2>
              <h3>I'm a big deal</h3>
              <p>Listen, I've had a pretty messed up day...</p>
          </ion-label>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item item-start>
          <item-avatar start>
              <img src="https://ionicframework.com/docs/demos/api/avatar/avatar.svg">
          </item-avatar>
          <ion-label>
              <h2>Finn</h2>
              <h3>I'm a big deal</h3>
              <p>Listen, I've had a pretty messed up day...</p>
          </ion-label>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item slot="start">
          <item-avatar start>
              <img src="https://ionicframework.com/docs/demos/api/avatar/avatar.svg">
          </item-avatar>
          <ion-label>
              <h2>Finn</h2>
              <h3>I'm a big deal</h3>
              <p>Listen, I've had a pretty messed up day...</p>
          </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Package JSON

```
"rxjs": "5.4.0",
"core-js": "2.4.1",
"zone.js": "0.8.12",
"typescript": "2.3.4",
"@angular/core": "5.2.9",
"@angular/http": "4.1.3",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"@angular/forms": "5.2.9",
"@angular/common": "5.2.9",
"@angular/compiler": "5.2.9",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.9"
```

below is the stackblitz url of project

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-mntalz

It should show the image in the left-hand side

Comment: which version you are using, of ionic?

Comment: I have updated my question with details and I have also mentioned the stackblitz url where the full code is available.

Comment: can u run "ionic info" command and show result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made a mistake at `<item-avatar start>`

Change to :

```
<ion-avatar item-start>
    <img src="https://ionicframework.com/docs/demos/api/avatar/avatar.svg">
 </ion-avatar>
```

Workin code :

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
      <ion-list-header>
          Recent Conversations
      </ion-list-header>
      <ion-item>
          <ion-avatar item-start>
              <img src="https://ionicframework.com/docs/demos/api/avatar/avatar.svg">
          </ion-avatar>
          <ion-label>
              <h2>Finn</h2>
              <h3>I'm a big deal</h3>
              <p>Listen, I've had a pretty messed up day...</p>
          </ion-label>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item item-start>
          <ion-avatar item-start>
              <img src="https://ionicframework.com/docs/demos/api/avatar/avatar.svg">
          </ion-avatar>
          <ion-label>
              <h2>Finn</h2>
              <h3>I'm a big deal</h3>
              <p>Listen, I've had a pretty messed up day...</p>
          </ion-label>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item slot="start">
         <ion-avatar item-start>
              <img src="https://ionicframework.com/docs/demos/api/avatar/avatar.svg">
          </ion-avatar>
          <ion-label>
              <h2>Finn</h2>
              <h3>I'm a big deal</h3>
              <p>Listen, I've had a pretty messed up day...</p>
          </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Reference Link: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/components/#multiline-list

Working demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-z5icij

Comment: This is not working, I have updated my question with details and I have also mentioned the stackblitz url where the full code is available.

Comment: @RaghavendraC my solution is working. Also checked on the https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-mntalz

Comment: it is showing ionic item text but not showing image (avatar). please send me your solution link in stack blitz if possible. so that I can compare and check.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake at

Change to :

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
   <ion-avatar item-start>
     <img src="img/avatar-cher.png">
   </ion-avatar>
   <h2>Cher</h2>
   <p>Ugh. As if.</p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Reference Link: [https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/components/#avatar-list](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/avatar)

you should remove extra "item-start" on other elements. Use only on avatar "item-start"

You need to check this answer.

Comment: this is not working, I have updated my question with details and I have also mentioned the stackblitz url where the full code is available.